# Use salesforce style sheets?

Tags: chatter, css, commandbutton, stylesheets

How can I use the built in salesforce style sheets to style a commandButton so that it looks like the (green) share button that is used in the chatter, post action? What class would I assign to styleClass? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below  CSS

```
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.08em;
background-color: #8ab529;
border: 1px solid #6c8049;
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#8AB529 0,#87AC31 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#8AB529 0,#87AC31 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#8AB529 0,#87AC31 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#8AB529 0,#87AC31 100%);
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
height: 30px;
color: #fff;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #adadad;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #adadad;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #adadad;
margin: 0;
```

Comment: I am looking into using the provided salesforce style sheets as opposed to creating my own css